# Which way of making a window in tkinter is better?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have seen two different tutorials on making a basic window using Tkinter. One of the tutorials uses a class with functions to initialize and assemble the window. In the other tutorial, they just made a window without using classes or functions.

Just to be clear, I'm NOT talking about what the windows do *per se*. I'm just wondering which method is better to implement Tkinter.

Here's the code for both if that explanation doesn't make sense.

Here's the code for both if that explanation doesn't make sense.

**CODE #1 uses classes**

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=NONE):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("GUI")  #

        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=1)

        # We created a button below to see how to do it but commented it out for now.
        '''closeButton = Button(self, text='Close', command=self.client_exit)  # Making a new button called closeButton.

        closeButton.place(x=0, y=0)  # Places the button at given co-ordinates. (0,0) is top left. This isn't cartesian.'''

        menuBar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menuBar)

        file = Menu(menuBar)
        file.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = self.client_exit)
        menuBar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu=file)

        edit = Menu(menuBar)
        edit.add_command(label = 'Show Image', command = self.showImg)
        edit.add_command(label = 'Show Text', command = self.showTxt)
        menuBar.add_cascade(label = 'Edit', menu=edit)

    def showImg(self):
        load = Image.open('CatPic.jpg')
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        catImage = Label(self, image=render)
        catImage.image = render
        catImage.place(x=250, y=250)

    def showTxt(self):
        writeText = Label(self, text = "Hi I'm Temmie")
        writeText.pack()



root = Tk()  # Tk() is a function within Tkinter. 'root' is the name of our Frame.
root.geometry("500x500")  # Defines size of 'root'.
root.mainloop()

app = Window(root)  # Finally, we use the Window class to make a window under the name 'app'.
```

**CODE #2 uses no such concept**

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()


topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1=Button(topFrame, text="Button 1", fg="red") #fg foreground is optional
button2=Button(topFrame, text="Button 2", fg="blue") #fg is optional
button3=Button(topFrame, text="Button 3", fg="green") #fg is optional
button4=Button(bottomFrame, text="Button 4", fg="black") #fg is optional

button1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()﻿
```

Comment: "better" is highly subjective, and relative to the complexity of the program you are writing. There can be arguments made about either approach.

Comment: I don't suppose it really matters, but your first example won't work. You can't create a window after you call `mainloop` because `mainloop` won't return until the root window has been destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you, I fixed it for myself.

Comment: Why have I been downvoted? :( I swear I searched for an answer to this before asking. This always seems to happen.

Comment: Haters will hate. This really is a debate for-against using OOP for everything, not only tKinter specific, but considering everyone's knowledge base is always different, I don't see anything really wrong with your question. Good luck and don't let it get you down.

Comment: @makaveli: perhaps it's because you didn't show any signs of research. You may have _done_ research but you didn't _show_ any research efforts. It could also be because this question can only be answered with opinions, which makes it off topic for this site.

Comment: @makaveli Alright, I won't.

Comment: @BryanOakley I didn't know this question could only be answered with opinions. I do understand the reason though.

Comment: @BryanOakley If the OP doesn't know it can only be answered with opinions, it does make sense and someone with similar thoughts might end up here, getting answers to questions they didn't know they have. But you have a point as well, I can't deny that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both pieces of code are doing basically the same stuff under the hood. The first piece takes the `Frame` as a base class and extends it with the default parameters and methods so that it can be used multiple times for a window that you like. So the first piece of code is how a normal OOP project would use tKinter so that one can basically modify everything and plug their own code whereever they feel that tKinter is lacking or misguided. At the same time all the modifications are easily usable for other projects (or other windows) and if you start working on another project that has all the same prerequisites, then you can just take your `Window` class and get cracking.

On the other hand the simpler solution takes advantage of all that tTkinter offers out of the box which means you can generate lots of customizable content with a few lines of code, using all tKinter settings, parameters and so on. The second solution is not so easily reusable and if you want certain parts of it, you can't just take the whole class definition, but have to pick out the lines that modify your window. Also when you get into a situation where you have to override tKinter stuff, you need to create your own `Window` class anyways. But then again, in most simpler projects that doesn't happen (I've written to projects using tKinter, both of them about 1500 lines, and neither of them required overriding the `Frame` class).

So TL;DR:
If you're an experienced OOP developer that has used all kinds of frameworks etc. beforehand, I would go for the first solution that overrides the `Frame` class.
If - as it seems from the question - you're a beginner who wants to get going and see a result instead of hassling with OOP quirks and other arguably unnecessary stuff for a simple project, I'd go for the second and lighter version.

PS! One should never use `from somepackage import *` because of name clashes, tracking imports in files and so on. Instead it is recommended to use just `import tkinter` and then you can access all of tKinter's stuff as `tkinter.Frame`, `tkinter.Button` etc. Also a good way is to import tKinter as `import tkinter as tk`, then you can use it as `tk.Frame`, `tk.Button` etc and all in all you have to write less. If you only want to use, say one or two components from a package, then you'd usually import them as `from tkinter import Button, Frame` and then use them just as `Button` and `Frame`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. Answered all my doubts really.

Answer (score 0):

It depends only on you.

---

For small examples I use mostly only functions - it is faster to write.
And beginners will understand it - they mostly don't know classes.

For something bigger I use classes - it makes code cleaner for me.

But I do this way not only in Tkinter but also in other modules - like PyGame.

Comment: Thank you furas. Good to know.